# Regex capture group in pandas extract call for single digit followed by single letter

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I need to extract substring instances in a pandas series that match this regex: `"[3-6]X"`
ie "3X", "4X", "5X", or "6X" from arbitrary strings like "Hello this is an 6X interesting sentence".

I have spent hours trying solutions, reading regex information, etc. I am not and will never be and am not interested in understanding regex in any detail, its only useful to me in small places very, very occasionally. I also have never encountered such a difficulty, I can usually search out a regex for my problem such as email-address matching, phone number matching, etc., and then copy-paste-modify with a bit of homework and get a solution in seconds or minutes. I have no idea what the problem is here that I'm not understanding, if its with my regex pattern, or how I'm using it with pandas. I realize that stack overflow is very high class and says I should not post this question, but I have spent 3 hours reading and trying solutions, and 60 hours a week for 10 years doing similar work and never encountered such a simple problem that posed such great difficulty.

work as expected:

`df.some_column.str.extract("([3-6])").fillna(False)`

`df.some_column.str.contains("[3-6]X").fillna(False)`

These give some matches for each of the digits when they occur and a lot of non-matching rows.

I have tried these (including chaining in `astype(str)` before the extract, just in case that makes a difference...) for example, with many many more variations of the regex string that I think are not helpful to list since they don't work. I have also tinkered with the `findall` and `contains` methods. `contains` works as expected with "[3-6]X", however `findall` and `extract` seem to need something different to match the same patterns.

Does not work:

`df.some_column.str.extract("([3-6]X)").fillna(False)`

`df.some_column.str.extract("([3-6]{X})").fillna(False)`

`df.some_column.str.extract("(\b[3-6])").fillna(False)`

I also threw in a word-break, which caused the extract to fail, even though every instance of the numbers I have are space-separated. Not sure if that's worth mentioning but it is baffling to me.

MWE

```
df = DataFrame({'a': ['sdfasd 3X dsflkjsafd', 'sdfpoiusdf 4X cat dog', 'cat dog hamburger']})

# expected
>>> df[df.a.str.contains("[3-6]X", na=False)].a                                                                                                                                                                                                 
0     sdfasd 3X dsflkjsafd                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
1    sdfpoiusdf 4X cat dog                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Name: a, dtype: object    

# unexpected, except that the MWE behaves as expected...
>>> df.a.str.extract("([3-6]X)")                                                                                                                                                                                                      
0    3X                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
1    4X                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
2    NaN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: Why `df.some_column.str.extract("([3-6]X)").fillna(False)` doesn't work? What result do you get?

Comment: Please read [mre] and [edit] your question to include sample input and output data, explaining what you expected to get and what you are getting.

Comment: I get a column of NA/False after the fillna for every "non-working" example.

Comment: @johnrobot As Nick stated - please [edit] your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output.

Comment: @AndrejKesely   I am working on enterprise data, and the MWE behaves as expected. I think it's an issue with the encoding or something. Appreciate the help but I may have to look into that possibility.

Comment: "*contains works as expected with "[3-6]X", however findall and extract seem to need something different to match the same patterns.*" Can you clarify how you came to this conclusion? What is the output of `df[df.a.str.extract("([3-6]X)", expand=False).notna() != df.a.str.contains("[3-6]X", na=False)]`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want [`pd.Series.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) to generate boolean mask:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": ["sdfasd 3X dsflkjsafd", "sdfpoiusdf 4X cat dog", "cat dog hamburger"]}
)

# make sure you have strings in the column - hence .astype(str)
out = df[df["a"].astype(str).str.contains(r"\b[1-4]X")]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                       a
0   sdfasd 3X dsflkjsafd
1  sdfpoiusdf 4X cat dog
```

Comment: The mask was accidentally carried into the MWE,  sorry for the confusion. The MWE and my actual case seem to behave differently, leading me to believe its an issue with the underlying data / string encoding if there isn't some issue with the regex string.

Comment: @johnrobot You should make an example that shows the undesired behaviour - the pattern `\b[1-4]X` should find all `1X`, `2X`, `3X`, `4X`. Make sure you have only strings in the column (not some other objects).

Comment: I cannot, when I copy a small portion of the data into new objects it behaves as I expect.

Comment: @johnrobot I think you have some other objects than strings in your dataframe. Try `out = df[df["a"].astype(str).str.contains(r"\b[1-4]X")]` (notice the `astype(str)`). Also, what e.g. `print(type(df["a"].iat[0]))` says?

Comment: `set([type(df["a"].iat[i]) for i in range(df.shape[0])])` gives `{<class 'str'>}` . Appreciate the help, still exploring solutions.